Is the State Transition Matrix the most important matrix in the Kalman Filter? Using the DLM package in R to run
I am trying to run an empirical model with time-varying parameters for its regression coefficients. Through the Kalman Filter, the parameters would vary under a random walk.
I noticed that the Kalman Filter has several methods of solving different matrices and introductions of computational-efficient or numerically stable algorithms for solving.
However, as to the best of my knowledge, I think there is no explicit guide on determining the components within these matrices aside from the initial measures that you could easily set a 0 filled vector for the mean and large uncertain numbers in the form of an identity matrix for the estimation error covariance.
How do we know what values to put in the state transition matrix, state covariance matrix, measurement coefficient matrix, and measurement covariance matrix? Most text books would say to experiment or based on previous research. Is there really no empirical way to determine what specific range or exact number for these relationships?
R Code
#DLM Package
library(dlm)

#Function for a Dynamic Cross-Sectional Absolute Deviation (Market Herding Empricial Model)

Dynamic_CSAD <- function(params) {
  
  #Observation Equation
  #Simply, a regression equation between the Cross-Sectional Absolute Deviation(CSAD) and the Absolute Market Returns and Squared Market Returns
 
  observation_model <- dlmModReg(
    cbind(Absolute_Market, Squared_Market),
    dV = V,# Set the Measurement Error Covariance Matrix as scalar with the single column observation of CSAD
    addInt = TRUE #Intercept Added
  )
  
  #Define the State Transition Models 
  #Tried Defining them together but kept on experiencing a problem
  state_model_lambda1 <- dlmModPoly(order = 1, dW = W1)  # lambda_1, t =  lambda_1, t - 1 + error term
  state_model_lambda2 <- dlmModPoly(order = 1, dW = W2)  # lambda_2, t =  lambda_2, t - 1 + error term

  #DLM Package Feature to Merge them
  combined_model <- obs_model + state_model_lambda1 + state_model_lambda2
  
  
  m0 <- rep(0, 3)  # Initial state vector
  C0 <- diag(1e7, 3)  # Initial estimation error covariance matrix
  FF <- matrix(c(1,0,0), nr=1) #Observation Matrix #Set 1 for Constants and 0 for Time-Varying (Written in the Guide)
  JFF <- matrix(c(0,1,1), nr=1) #Observation Transition Matrix for Time-Varying Parameters (Exact Opposite)
  GG <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), nr=3) #State Transition Matrix of 3 by 3 Matrix. Identity Matrix?
  
  combined_model$m0 <- m0
  combined_model$C0 <- C0
  combined_model$FF <- FF
  combined_model$JFF <- JFF
  combined_model$GG <- GG
  
  
  return(combined_model)
}

The question is why does the GG or the state transition matrix matter the most. I experimented with all the matrices and found that the results would change drastically under different state transition matrices.
DLM Package Reference by Giovanni Petris:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf
Disclaimer: I am not a professional in this subject. Thank you for your kind understanding.

Welcome to StackOverflow, PHP. Although you're using R, your question does not address a programming issue with the R language (and, thus, will probably get closed). Instead,  https://stats.stackexchange.com is a very helpful platform for questions about statistics (regardless of the software involved).

Thank you for the redirection. I will just repost it there.
